# RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult() no longer exist, what can I replace that with for DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I was trying to replicate what Rick is doing here for OpenID implementation:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx

However, when I get to this part:

```
return req.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

Then I cannot continue, as AsActionResult is no longer exists, is there any replacement of this?

Thanks alot

Comment: not enough tutorials include namespace requirements, and that control-<period> is not always enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It still exists.  It is an extension method that you only get by having this at the top of your file:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
```

Comment: It no longer seems to be in the dll anymore.